# Why is upcasting necessary in this Scala code?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, upcasting

This compiles:

```
import scala.collection._

trait Foo[A, +This <: SortedSet[A] with SortedSetLike[A,This]]
extends SortedSetLike[A, This] { this: This =>

  def bar: This = (this: SortedSetLike[A,This]).empty

}
```

But if the upcast is removed it fails to compile:

```
import scala.collection._

trait Foo[A, +This <: SortedSet[A] with SortedSetLike[A,This]]
extends SortedSetLike[A, This] { this: This =>

  def bar: This = this.empty

}
```

Why? From the `extends` clause we know that `Foo` is a `SortedSetLike[A, This]`, so the upcast is valid of course - but doesn't this show that the compiler has allowed conflicting inheritance to occur?

Comment: I don't know the exact details of this case, but it's another example of the horrible stuff that can happen because methods in subclasses can have more specific return types than the method signatures they implement.

Answer (score 6):

The **SortedSetLike** trait inherits the *empty* method from **SetLike**.

```
/** The empty set of the same type as this set
* @return  an empty set of type `This`.
*/
def empty: This
```

But **SortedSet** overrides the *empty* method and has an explicit return type:

```
/** Needs to be overridden in subclasses. */
override def empty: SortedSet[A] = SortedSet.empty[A]
```

Since you specify that **This** is a subclass of **SortedSet** the compiler will find **SortedSet**'s implementation of *empty* first, which returns a **SortedSet**.  The compiler does not know how to convert the resulting **SortedSet** to your **This** subclass.

But if you upcast to the **SortedSetLike** trait the compiler will find its *empty* method which returns a **This**.