# Play Framework, Format[A] vs OFormat[A]

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I can't find an explanation in the Play Framework docs.
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289702/play-framework-2-4-writes-a-vs-owrites-a-formata-vs-oformata-purpose) but now I can't see why will I use Format[A] at all.

Comment: `OFormat` will only read/write JSON objects, but maybe you have some types that you want to read/write as JSON string/int/Boolean..

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: imagine a `case class Wrapper(str: String)` that you want to serialize as a plain JSON string `"..."` but not as `{str: ""}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Gaël mentioned:
`OFormat` will only read/write JSON objects, but maybe you have some types that you want to read/write as JSON string/int/Boolean.

OFormat/OWrite returns a JsObject while Format/Write returns JsValue.
You can do more with JsObject because it is a subclass of JsValue that represents a JSON object. JsValue can be a string, numeric, object or array.